# Why am I getting error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found when trying to use OpenHtmlToPdf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, openhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use OpenHtmlToPdf to convert a Html file to pdf.
This is the code i'm trying to run:

```
using System.IO;
using OpenHtmlToPdf;

namespace Converter{
    class Html_to_Pdf
    {
        static void Main(string[] args){
            var html = Pdf.From(@"C:/Temp/input.html").OfSize(PaperSize.A4);
            byte[] content = html.Content();
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:/Temp/output.pdf", content);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error that i get when i try to compile the code:

```
[Running] dotnet "C:\Users\janik\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\cs-script.user\dotnet\cscs.dll" "d:\Github\ionesoft_ebook_to_pdf\Scripts\converter.cs"
Error: Specified file could not be compiled.

d:\Github\ionesoft_ebook_to_pdf\Scripts\converter.cs(2,7): error CS0246:  The type or namespace name "OpenHtmlToPdf" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
d:\Github\ionesoft_ebook_to_pdf\Scripts\converter.cs(2,7): error CS0246:  The type or namespace name "OpenHtmlToPdf" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


[Done] exited with code=0 in 2.183 seconds
```

So what am i doing wrong here because according to me i'm not mussung anything.
I'm using visual studio code but i don't know if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command `dotnet add package OpenHtmlToPdf` to add a reference to you project. This will add a package reference in your .csproj file. Once done run this command `dotnet restore` to restore your packages.

For your reference: [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package)

Edit:
You can Add [Nuget Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager&ssr=false#overview) Extension. After it is Added, perform below steps:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Type OpenHtmlToPdf
3. Choose Package and then the version number.

Comment: I did that but it didn't help, i still get the same error message.

Comment: @Janik313 I have added an edit, please check.